# How can i display custom events into a chart?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to use custom log event to have some statistics of the use of my app.
Events are properly configured and can be seen in the "Stream view" of firebase analytics.

my problem is that i want to display statistics no for only the last 30min.
for exemple if i log an event "car" which contain the property model, which can have the value 'tesla', 'ford' etc... as this : 
this.defaultAnalytics.logEvent("car", {model: "tesla"});
I'm able to see in the last 30min like 75% of car.model are tesla in the stream view, but i'm not able to see this for the last week for exemple.
I can only see that the event 'car' has been emit 100 times in the last week but i can't see anything about the value of the property.

I'm i obliged to use a tool as bigquery ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which charts you want to get, but in general - you don't have to use BigQuery. You can see all your custom event parameters in Firebase console, but you have to [register them first](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en):

> You can also identify up to 100 custom event parameters per project (50 numeric and 50 text) to include in reporting by registering those parameters with their corresponding events. Once you register your custom parameters, Google Analytics for Firebase displays a corresponding data card in each related event-detail report.